# $\forall k\in \Bbb N, A_k $ are closed, show $\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k}$ may not be closed.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Suppose that sets $A_{k}, k \in \mathbb{N}$, are all closed.

Give an example to show that $\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k}$ need not be closed.

Can I say $[1/n , -1/n]$ is an example?

Comment: Take any countable set that is not closed, such as the rationals, and write that set as a union of singleton sets.

Comment: Better $A_k=[-1+1/k ,1 -1/k]$.

Comment: Or even $A_k=[\frac{1}{k},+\infty)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way of doing this is to use a problem you already know how to solve (hopefully): exhibit an example of infinitely many open sets whose intersection is not open (e.g. $\left(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)$) and take complements.

Comment: so you mean my example will be the complement of $\cap _{k} B_{k} = (-1\k, 1\k)$ and the intersection is the closed set {0}

Comment: and using that $(-\infty , 1/k]$ is a closed set .... correct?

Comment: So you have that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right) = \{0\}$. Then, remembering that the complement of an intersection is the union of the complements, you take complements of both sides to get a union of closed sets equal something that's not a closed set. The point is that don't need to verify that the resulting sets on the left will be closed or the one on the right is not closed, because that follows from the original ones being open/not open.

Answer (score 4):

No, $[1/n,-1/n]$ cannot be an example, because if $A_k=[1/n, -1/n]$, then, assuming $n>0$,  $$\cup_{k=1}^\infty A_k=\emptyset$$

and $\emptyset$ is a closed set.

However, an example is very close to what you wrote. Your *idea* is quite OK. Your execution is extremely sloppy.

Comment: @postmortes Since $1/n > -1/n$, I think $[1/n, -1/n]=\emptyset$, wouldn't you agree? :)

Comment: ah, you're being strict about the order as well!  Then I retract my comment :)

Comment: @postmortes Of course I am! I am trying to point out *all* of the sloppy mistakes OP made. They include reversing the order, and also defining $A_k$ in terms of $n$, instead of $k$.

Comment: Then allow me to upvote you :)

Answer (score 1):

For $k=1,2,\dots ,$ let $A_k=\{1/k\}.$ Then each $A_k$ is closed in $\mathbb R.$ But

$$\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k = \{1,1/2,1/3,\dots\},$$

which is not closed in $\mathbb R,$ since $0\notin \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k.$